# Parsing a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am trying to parse a text file that is populated with names,age and other information about a person, like this:

```
Number 1
Date 01/01/2001
Name John
Age 20
Job Programmer
```

So when the first string of the row is Name in the rest of the row i have a string, when the first string is Age i expect a number.
What i want is to check that i have a match between the first string in the row and the rest of the row. So if i have Name 20 in the same row i should get an error message.
How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - parsing a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528281/ruby-parsing-a-text-file)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ty for the reply,already seen that thread, the answer is old and i wanted to know if there is a different and better approach.

Comment: What about `line.split` then check the 2nd element of the array against the 1st?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How can i do this?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Always write what code you had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the format of your file, you can check for the presence of integer in the line, and then perform your checks

```
@a={};File.foreach('f1.txt') do |f| # foreach ensures reading line by line without slurping the entire file into memory
  # add first word as key = create array with rest of data and add note if it is number or stirng
  @a[f.split.first] = [f.split.last, (f.scan(/\d+/).empty?) ? "string" : "number"]
  puts
end

=> {"Number"=>["1", "number"], "Date"=>["01/01/2001", "number"], "Name"=>["John", "string"], "Age"=>["20", "number"], "Job"=>["Programmer", "string"]}
```

Comment: thankyou arjun, and if there are more complex lines,like email a@g.com, i should use regex to see that the text is correct,right?

Comment: Yeah you can perform your checks the way you like after you get the hash. But if you have a choice on the format of the file, perhaps this is better suited as CSV or YML or even JSON

Comment: that will work, i will try to expand my exercise in this directions, ty again